# package.json for global module installation

Tags: node.js, package, npm, node-modules

I have a package.json in which some modules have to be installed globally,below is the part that i added below dependencies

```
 "scripts": {
  "preinstall": "npm i -g supervisor",
   "preinstall": "npm i -g forever"

   }
```

But when i ran npm install i got the error as below

```
npm WARN package.json aaa@0.0.0 No README.md file found!
npm WARN cannot run in wd aaa@0.0.0 npm i -g forever (wd=/home/administrator/AAA)
```

All the modules to be installed locally are getting  installed,but only gloal installation is throwing an error.I am stuck here any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your package.json :

```
"config":{
    "unsafe-perm":true
}
```

And install your module as `root`.

Also I think that the switch `preferGlobal` : [Documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html), is created for modules that prefer to be installed globally. You might want to change your program logic to use programatically `forever` module.

Answer (score 0):

Install your modules locally and then execute them via the bin folder in the local `node_modules` directory

```
npm install -S forever
ls node_modules/.bin/
```

To start your app execute

```
node_modules/.bin/forever start app.js
```

Comment: While this may be a solution, there are still modules that should be installed (and invoked) globally, like `grunt-cli`