# npm install couldnt install angularjs libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, ubuntu, npm

I have installed [mean.io](http://mean.io/#!/) and ran sudo npm install. Actually following commands in sequence

```
sudo npm install -g meanio
mean init yourNewApp
cd yourNewApp
sudo npm install -g bower
sudo npm install
```

It is supposed to download and install angularjs libraries into public/system/lib. After doing the above steps public /system/lib is not created due to which when I start the application I get the error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, open '/home/santhosh/dev/scaleqa/mean_tut/old mean/temp/myapp/public/system/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Is it  something to do with certain npm/angularjs server being down. I have faced this problem earlier also but got fixed on 2nd try and I didn't bother to do more research. This became a big issue when I try to pull my repo into cloud and start the application. public/system/lib is added in  .gitignore by default and is expected to be created during npm install.

I get following warnings with sudo npm install

```
npm WARN package.json mean-connect-mongo@0.4.3 No repository field.
npm WARN cannot run in wd mean@0.3.3 node node_modules/bower/bin/bower install (wd=/home/santhosh/dev/scaleqa/mean_tut/old mean/temp/myapp)
```

this is [link](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/package.json) to package.json

Comment: Can you try running `npm install` without `sudo`, so just `$ npm install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem maybe related to running `npm install` as `sudo`, which can cause problems.  [As mentioned in another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136746/npm-install-failed-with-cannot-run-in-wd), this can be worked around in a couple ways.  But because it looks like this is being run from your home directory, you really shouldn't need to run `npm install` as root.

Try to issue the same commands, but the last without `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g meanio
mean init yourNewApp
cd yourNewApp
sudo npm install -g bower
npm install
```

Note that the reason you may need to run `npm install -g <package>` using `sudo` is because by default npm uses `/usr/local` for global installs, which can be a restricted directory.  However, when you install a package locally (without the `-g` flag) you should not need to run as root.

Comment: I got the error mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo but solved with sudo chown -R `whoami` .npm

Comment: If you're still getting errors when running `npm install`, try running `npm cache clear` and try again.