# NodeJS unsafe-perm not working on package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to run a `npm install` command with a preinstall script at my `package.json`. I know it's antipattern but I need to run some scripts as root.

It's working fine by adding a `.npmrc` file containing `unsafe-perm = true` to my root directory. But it's not working by add a config property in my `package.json` file:

```
   {
     "name": "foo",
     "version": "1.4.4",
     "config": {
        "unsafe-perm":true
     },
     "scripts" :  { 
        "preinstall" : "npm install -g bower"
     }
   }
   // It is not working
```

According with [NPM config docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm) it's ok adding this property in my package file. I want to understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add that property, you are adding it to the environment of your script with the prefix `npm_config_package`:

```
$ cat package.json
{
 "config": { "unsafe-perm": true }
}
$ npm run env | grep perm
$ npm run env | grep perm
npm_package_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_config_unsafe_perm=true
$ sudo npm run env | grep perm
npm_package_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_config_unsafe_perm=
$
```

This is for security reasons, sort of.  It would not be good for an arbitrary package from the `npm` registry to allow you to change `npm`'s config settings (e.g., what if it set prefix to `/etc` and installed a file named `passwd`)

However you can still get around it by setting the environment variable in on your script line (this will not work on Windows):

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "config": { "unsafe-perm": true },
  "scripts": { "foo": "npm_config_unsafe_perm=true env" }
 }
$ npm run foo | grep unsafe_perm
npm_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_package_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_lifecycle_script=npm_config_unsafe_perm=true env
npm_package_scripts_foo=npm_config_unsafe_perm=true env
$ sudo npm run foo | grep unsafe_perm
npm_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_package_config_unsafe_perm=true
npm_lifecycle_script=npm_config_unsafe_perm=true env
npm_package_scripts_foo=npm_config_unsafe_perm=true env
$
```

This may be a bug in `npm` though, so I would recommend not relying on this behavior.  Can you get away with using a different user than `root`?

Source: Tested with `npm@2.6.1` on OSX.  I am a support volunteer on the `npm` issue tracker, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues.

Comment: Does this work with Node.js v10.15.13, npm 6.4.1, Windows 10 environment?

Answer (score 2):

unsafe-perm

Default: false if running as root, true otherwise
Type: Boolean
Set to true to suppress the UID/GID switching when running package scripts. If set explicitly to false, **then installing as a non-root user will fail**.

see the https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#unsafe-perm

Comment: I have read that. My problem is I need to run with this property set to true as root user. That's the point of my question

Comment: This property can be set on the [commandline](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config) when calling npm, even as root: sudo npm install --unsafe-perm true PACKAGE_NAME