# Set config block in package.json doesn't work

Tags: npm, package.json

For some reason I need to run npm install under root user, so I need to specify `unsafe-perm=true` in order to execute a bash script, it works when I using

1. `npm install --unsafe-perm=true`
   or
2. `npm config set unsafe-perm=true` (equals to write into ~/.npmrc)

But it won't work if I add a config block into package.json

```
{
 "name": "on-http",
 "config": {
   "unsafe-perm": "true"
 },
...
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28763958/nodejs-unsafe-perm-not-working-on-package-json

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I tried that, but it didn't solve the problem