# postinstall: cannot run in wd un in wd %s %s (wd=%s)

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp

npm WARN lifecycle angular-seed-advanced@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) angular-seed-advanced@0.0.0 gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && npm run nativescript-install && node tools/install.js /Users/xxxx/Downloads/angular-seed-advanced-master

Answer (score 7):

The question doesn't provide much context but I experienced the same problem when running

```
npm install
```

to build the [Angular Seed Project](https://mgechev.github.io/angular-seed/) inside a Docker Container. In my case it was due to running npm with root privileges.

To try to resolve the issue check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19132229).

What worked for me was:

- option 1 of the above answer:

  `npm install --unsafe-perm`
- not running npm with root privileges